# trying to echo mysql connect or not

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error on line 4. why? i am trying to connect to mysql database and see either it connected or not. i am not getting any result.

**jcon.php**

```
 <?php 
    require 'config.php';
    $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DB);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    else{ echo "mysql connected succesfully";}
    ?>
```

**config.php**

```
<?php
define( "HOST","localhost");
define ("DB","share");
deifne ("DBUSER";"root");
define ("DBPASS"; "" );
?>
```

Comment: If you're starting your question with "Getting an error" you might aswell post the error itself.

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/367456)

Comment: Defining constants needs a `,` separator between name and value, instead of `;`

Comment: looks like you've got this problem once a week and need to ask the question again and again or what? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286651/connection-to-mysql-using-mysqli-command-is-not-working

Comment: `<?php 
require 'jcon.php';
if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["firstname"],$_POST["password"])){
 $username=$_POST["username"];
 $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
 $password=$_POST["password"];
}
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO member (username, firstname, password)
VALUES ($username, $firstname,$password)");
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Dear {$firstname} ! you have been successfully registered. "
?>` i am seeing an error at line 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`deifne ("DBUSER";"root");` seems to be problematic

Comment: and `define ("DBPASS"; "" );`

Comment: Oh yes. Typo found. Well done that man

Comment: `<?php 
require 'jcon.php';
if(isset($_POST["username"], $_POST["firstname"],$_POST["password"])){
 $username=$_POST["username"];
 $firstname=$_POST["firstname"];
 $password=$_POST["password"];
}
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO member (username, firstname, password)
VALUES ($username, $firstname,$password)");
if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "Dear {$firstname} ! you have been successfully registered. "
?>` line 10 showing error..